# how can I get average color in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, colors, average

In flutter there is palette generator package, but these package are not exact for getting color average.

I want to make a color average function in flutter(dart)
I found some code for getting average color. but I want to convert in to dart code of flutter code.
how do i make the function?
I want to get average color with Fileimage
thank you.

--------------------------- this is the code I found. I want to convert into dart(flutter) code ---------------------

```
Bitmap bitmap = someFunctionReturningABitmap();
long redBucket = 0;
long greenBucket = 0;
long blueBucket = 0;
long pixelCount = 0;

for (int y = 0; y < bitmap.getHeight(); y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < bitmap.getWidth(); x++)
    {
        Color c = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);

        pixelCount++;
        redBucket += Color.red(c);
        greenBucket += Color.green(c);
        blueBucket += Color.blue(c);
        // does alpha matter?
    }
}

Color averageColor = Color.rgb(redBucket / pixelCount,
                                greenBucket / pixelCount,
                                blueBucket / pixelCount);
```

Comment: I want to get average color with FileImage

Comment: This is not a question for a specific problem but trying to recruit someone to code this in dart for you.

Answer (score 4):

The code's almost identical, in dart it would become something like this:

```
import 'package:image/image.dart' as img;

img.Image bitmap =
      img.decodeImage(new File('assets/images/keyboard.jpg').readAsBytesSync());

  int redBucket = 0;
  int greenBucket = 0;
  int blueBucket = 0;
  int pixelCount = 0;

  for (int y = 0; y < bitmap.height; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < bitmap.width; x++) {
      int c = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);

      pixelCount++;
      redBucket += img.getRed(c);
      greenBucket += img.getGreen(c);
      blueBucket += img.getBlue(c);
    }
  }

  Color averageColor = Color.fromRGBO(redBucket ~/ pixelCount,
      greenBucket ~/ pixelCount, blueBucket ~/ pixelCount, 1);
```

I Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome, feel free to mark it as the best answer if it helped you!

Comment: The inner for should loop through the width, not the height

Comment: I got `The function 'getRed' isn't defined.`

Answer (score 0):

If anyone finds this in 2024, I updated the accepted answer to match the current version of the Image library.

```dart
import 'package:image/image.dart' as img;

  Color getImageColor(File imageFile) {
    img.Image? image = img.decodeImage(imageFile.readAsBytesSync());
    if (image == null) {
      return Colors.black;
    }
    double red = 0;
    double green = 0;
    double blue = 0;
    double count = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < image.width; x++) {
      for (int y = 0; y < image.height; y++) {
        img.Pixel pixel = image.getPixel(x, y);
        red = red + pixel.r;
        green = green + pixel.g;
        blue = blue + pixel.b;
        count = count + 1;
      }
    }
    int rf = red ~/ count;
    int gf = green ~/ count;
    int bf = blue ~/ count;
    return Color.fromRGBO(rf, gf, bf, 1);
  }
```